# Swift 4: @IBOutlet UITextView crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, iboutlet, nsexception

I use a table view embedded in a view controller. I stored in the table view some items like `UITextField`, `UISlider`, and so on. When I connect these items in the class, the app crashes on the `UITextView` outlet.

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameProfileTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var ageSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionProfileTextView: UITextView! //Crash here!
```

The error message does not help me. Console only shows the message below with no more details.

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

The `@IBOutlet` connection seems to be ok as the image below shows.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the build folder? And restarting Xcode :)

Comment: try to remove connection(outlet) and connect again

Comment: The console should say more, are sure it doesn't say something like "Found unexpected nil while unwrapping an optional"?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already tried restart Xcode, clear the project, connect the uitextView again and delete the UITextView and connect it again. No success.

Comment: Emilio, all the console shows is "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) "

Comment: @Enzo Your IBOutlets on UITableViewCell or UIViewController?

Comment: Maxim Zakopaylov, the IBOutlets is on UITableViewCell. The table is embedded in a Container View, on a View Controler. Each cell has one or two @IBOutlets but just UITextView is causing problem.

Comment: @Enzo I think your UItextView is not on UITableViewCell, maybe it's on different view? Can you show screenshot with all storyboard?

Comment: @MaximZakopaylov, you are correct. The outlets are not connected on UITableViewCell. They are connected ia a UITableViewController.

Comment: @Enzo did my hint help you?

Comment: @Maxim Zakopaylov, 
I solved the problem recreating the Views, but thanks for showing a different approach, this would be my next step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IBOutlet links **from** interface builder **to** the relevant UIViewController seem fine.

It might be that the IBOutlet on the UIViewController has more than 1 pointer associated to it.

If you right click on the grey dot on the left of the IBOutlet in the related UIViewController is there only 1 reference?

e.g.

[image]

If this doesn't work I would suggest deleting UIViewController in interface builder and starting again.

Comment: Worked. I deleted the View Controller and the Table View Controller. After that I created all items again:View Controller , Table View Controller, UITextView, UITextField, so on and I did reconnected UITextView and other elements on UITableViewController class. Thank you @kd02 and Thank you to everyone who answered.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the connections and reconnect. Check if the class name is the same in the file and in the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Artyon. I already tried delete and recreate the connection and didn´t work. Latter, I will check the class name again, but the others IBOutlets is in the same table and does not trigger error.

Comment: Hmm, strange, need more information or screenshot. @Enzo